# specification of list of servers in zookeeper cluster

Tags: apache-zookeeper

Is the second component of the list of zookeepers just a sequence numbering or does it have to correspond to the `myId` of the instance? For instance if I set up a new node with `myId=4` and take deprovision the instance with `myId=3` of the existing nodes, would my config have to look like the following:

```
tickTime=2000 
dataDir=/usr/src/zookeeper
clientPort=2181
initLimit=10
syncLimit=5
server.1=192.168.1.2:2888:3888
server.2=192.168.1.3:2888:3888
server.4=192.168.1.5:2888:3888
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It corresponds to the `myId` of the instance.

> Every machine that is part of the ZooKeeper ensemble should know about
>   every other machine in the ensemble. You accomplish this with the
>   series of lines of the form server.id=host:port:port. The parameters
>   host and port are straightforward. You attribute the server id to each
>   machine by creating a file named myid, one for each server, which
>   resides in that server's data directory, specified by the
>   configuration file parameter dataDir.

Source: http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/trunk/zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_zkMulitServerSetup